# How to open shortcut (.lnk) properties window programmatically?

Tags: c#, shell, shortcut-file

I've been googling around for a while now, but without any luck. I'd like to be able to launch shortcut properties window of certain .lnk-file directly from my code. I mean the window that you can open by right-clicking shortcut icon and choosing "Properties".

Comment: Use the Process class.  Set ProcessStartInfo.Verb to "Properties".

Comment: Thanks Hans! Worked perfectly :)