# Run an application via shortcut

Tags: c#, exception, process, shortcut

I've manually created a shortcut for another application (original file has *.exe* extension). If I try to run it by double-clicking on the shortcut with my mouse, it works perfectly as it should. However, when I try to do the same thing in my application via `Process.Start`, it doesn't work.

```
var myProcess = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "D:\\shortcut.lnk"
    }
};
myProcess.Start();
```

`myProcess.Start()` throws an `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation`.

Here are some thing I've already tried (according to this post [Run an application via shortcut using Process.Start()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141821/run-an-application-via-shortcut-using-process-start), so my post is not a duplicate as nothing stated there works):

1. Setting up target platform to x64 - same exception.
2. `ErrorDialog = true` - same exception but in a new popup.
3. `UseShellExecute = true` - same exception.
4. `UseShellExecute = false` - `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid Win32 application`.

Tried on Windows 8, Windows 10 and Windows 11, .net Framework 4.7.2. Getting the same results every time.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41912943/982149

Comment: Gotcha. So I have to get the executable path that shortcut links to, and launch exe directly.

Comment: This is obviously should be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141821/run-an-application-via-shortcut-using-process-start, but you claim that none of the options work.... Please make sure to edit in the link to that existing question as explanation that it is not a duplicate. Possibly edit in version of Windows/.Net you have problem with. (@Fildor existing post claims otherwise)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov revisited and I think you are right. No 4. from question actually _should_ have worked, in that it "followed the link" _but_ then the executable wasn't right, it seems.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't think it has something to do with the Windows version since I get the same results on 3 different PCs with Windows 8, Windows 10 and Windows 11. .net Framework version is 4.7.2.